# Doing certain actions upon user creation in Django

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth, receiver

I'm using social-auth-app-django to do social authentication with Facebook and Google. I'm trying to create a receiver once a user has been created to perform certain commands such as showing a tutorial (only once) after user creation.

Below is what I'm trying to do but haven't been able to get it to work.

```
from social_core.pipeline.user import create_user

@receiver(create_user)
def after_user_created(request, user, **kwargs):
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)
    userprofile.full_name = user.first_name + " " + user.last_name
    userprofile.save()
    request.session['first_login'] = True
    return render_to_response("main/highlights/highlights.html",locals(),RequestContext(request))
```

Essentially, how can I create some sort of receiver to activate once I create a unique user so that I can perform custom actions once that user has been created? My current code doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

In your app models.py write a pre save signal as shown below:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def show_tutorial(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    # For first time creation of user display tutorial
    if instance._state.adding:
        # display tutorial()
```

Comment: I tried doing what you said and putting a  request.session['first_login'] = True, where you put the #display tutorial () but I'm getting this error: missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'